# How can I use the indexed numerical value of a factor level in r?

Tags: r, statistics, subset

I have a factor variable with a single column of data. It contains 33 levels, and as I understand each individual level has an integer value from 1-33. I was wondering how I could refer to that value rather than the levels label when subsetting a row?

Heres my attemp at writing the code for it:

Bexley <- subset(LE2016, borough[3])

I am trying to create a new object 'Bexley' containing only the level which was assigned the integer value of 3 from the dataframe 'LE2016'.

Thanks

Comment: Could you put a reproducible example?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking for. Something like this? LE2016 <- data.frame(borough = factor(1:30)); library(dplyr);
Bexley <- filter(LE2016, borough == 3)

Comment: Extract the levels of a factor in a variable:
    lev<-levels(factor_Variable)
Then you can use this "lev" variable containing levels of your factor for subsetting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `c` or `as.numeric` to coerce the factor to integer and then do the subsetting. Here is a simple example:

```
library(dplyr)
DF <- data.frame(f=factor(c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"), levels=c("a", "b", "c")))
DF
  f
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 a
5 b
6 c
# filter out the 3th level
DF %>% filter(c(f) == 3)
  f
1 c
2 c

# c will coerce factor to integer
c(DF$f)
[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
```